# How to display two images in desktop view and mobile view separately.

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml

I created an example project to display images from an XML file. Basically, It is displaying image as a background image in both desktop and mobile view. I need to display two images in desktop view and mobile view as a background images separately.

Here is the xml code,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<paintings>
<cd>
  <head>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</head>
  <image>https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Liliumbulbiferumflowertop.jpg/220px-Liliumbulbiferumflowertop.jpg</image>
  <image_mobile>https://thoughtcatalog.files.wordpress.com/2018/06/flower-puns.jpg</image_mobile>
</cd>

<cd>
  <head>posuere lacus in, accumsan nulla.</head>
  <image>https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/SpMAAOSwceNZXpSZ/s-l300.jpg</image>
  <image_mobile>https://cdn.britannica.com/s:700x450/45/5645-004-7461C1BD.jpg</image_mobile>
</cd>

<cd>
  <head>per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</head>
  <image>https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/883859744498176000/pjEHfbdn_400x400.jpg</image>
  <image_mobile>https://www.lumixgexperience.panasonic.co.uk/app/uploads/gallery/AdamTrevor/Flower_HDR.jpg</image_mobile>
</cd>

<cd>
  <head>per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</head>
  <image>https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/883859744498176000/pjEHfbdn_400x400.jpg</image>
  <image_mobile>http://clipart-library.com/images/6iy5aE5nT.jpg</image_mobile>
</cd>

</paintings>
```

Herewith attached the example that I was done.

Plunker- http://next.plnkr.co/edit/LeyIh69Ik3vnZLIn?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview

Comment: If it's a mobile view then change it to let image = '<img style="background-image:url(' + $(this).find("image_mobile").text() + ')"' + '" />';

Comment: @NarendraMongiya Can you help me to implement if function also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to detect the whether it is mobile device.

```
var isMobile = false; //initiate as false
// device detection
if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|iris|kindle|Android|Silk|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(navigator.userAgent) 
    || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(navigator.userAgent.substr(0,4))) { 
    isMobile = true;
}
```

and in your XML Parser function, replace the let image with the below code

```
let image = '';
        if(isMobile){
image = '<img style="background-image:url(' + $(this).find("image_mobile").text() + ')"' + '" />';
        }else{
image = '<img style="background-image:url(' + $(this).find("image").text() + ')"' + '" />';
        }
```

Comment: Can you add it into plunker example? When I add it, it is not working.

Comment: added that, are you able to see that?